# Redirection differences between &> >& and 2>&1

Tags: shell, zsh, io-redirection

On [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file) and a few other threads I have seen the following commands for redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to a file.

Are they all equivalent? Is there any difference between them?

```
command1 >> logfile 2>&1
command &> logfile
command >& logfile
```

Comment: The last two are equivilent: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11255447/1032785

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have tagged `zsh`, let me tell you that all the 3 redirections works exactly the same way. As you might have read in both the duplicate posts (the one in the comment and the one in your post), they all redirect `stderr` to `stdout` which inturn is redirected to the file 'logfile' (ie, the logfile will contain both the output and errors).

But their behaviour changes a LOT depending on the shell you are in.

All the three styles of redirections works well in the same way in `bash` and `zsh`

**But:**

Only `>&` works in `csh` or `tcsh`

```
[soum@server ~]$  ./test.sh > logfile 2>&1
Ambiguous output redirect.
[soum@server ~]$ ./test.sh &> logfile
Invalid null command.
[soum@server ~]$ ./test.sh >& logfile
[soum@server ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
[soum@server ~]$
```

In `ksh` only `2>&1` works.

```
$ ./test.sh >& logfile
-ksh: logfile: bad file unit number
$ ./test.sh &> logfile
[1]     23039
$ 1  2  3  4  5  6  logfile  test.sh
ls: cannot access ttr: No such file or directory

[1] +  Done(2)                 ./test.sh &> logfile
```

I hate `ksh`. While `>&` just gave an error, the `&>` backgrounded a part of the command and emptied the logfile (if non-empty).

Comment: What did you mean `sh`? If it's POSIX shell, `&>` and `>&` won't work.

Comment: Sadly the first statement is factually incorrect. See my answer for clobber vs append.

Answer (score 1):

### `&>` and `>&` semi-equivalence (clobber)

The [`zsh` manual Redirections section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) says that:

- `&>`
- `>&`

are equivalent.

Both will clobber the file - truncate it file to 0 bytes before writing to it, just like `> file` would do in the STDIN-only case.

**However**, the [`bash` manual Redirections section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) adds that:

> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> When using the second form, *word* may not expand to a number or `-`. If it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating File Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

So, whilst you tagged `zsh`, it's probably good practice to get finger memory in the first form should one ever write a `bash` script.

### `>> logfile 2>&1` and `&>>` equivalence (append)

Here, `logfile` is not overwritten, but opened for writing at the end of the file, ie append mode (`O_APPEND`).

The equivalent in both `{ba,z}sh` is:

```
command1 &>> logfile
```

In `bash`:

> The format for appending standard output and standard error is:
>
> ```
> &>>word
> ```
>
> This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >>word 2>&1
> ```
>
> (see Duplicating File Descriptors below).

(Note: the clobber usage of `&>` over `>&` in the section above is again recommended given there is only one way for appending in `bash`.)

`zsh` allows both `&>>` and `>>&` forms.