# Ambiguous output redirect

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to redirect stderr to stdout and then out to a file in an init script, but when I introduce stderr to stdout I get the “Ambiguous output redirect” error. Stdout alone does not result in the error, and writes to the log file where I stated. I've tried the following

```
-jar /jbeaulau_test/microservices/config-server-0.0.2-RELEASE.jar &>/jbeaulau_test/microservices/log/all.log &

-jar /jbeaulau_test/microservices/config-server-0.0.2-RELEASE.jar >/jbeaulau_test/microservices/log/all.log 2>&1 &
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Advice: (1) Don’t give example commands that are > 100 characters long if you don’t have to.  You could demonstrate the problem with `echo &> foo`.  (2) Don’t give example commands that are asynchronous if you don’t have to.  (3) Learn about shells.  There’s more than one shell in the Unixverse, and they accept different command syntaxes.  Learn how to tell what shell you’re using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stderr redirection not working in csh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/stderr-redirection-not-working-in-csh)

Comment: See also [Inconsistency of stderr redirection between tcsh and other shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197878/23408), [What are the shell’s control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408), [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70963/23408) and [Redirection differences between &> >& and 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176216/23408).

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have noted this is in Bash

Comment: @jbeaulau Are you sure it's bash ? Check `echo $0` and  if you're using Linux, `cat /proc/$$/cmdline`

Answer (score 6):

If you're running (t)csh, you get `Ambiguous output redirect.` if you try to set up two conflicting redirections:

```
> echo foo > a > b
Ambiguous output redirect.
```

In Bash, you could get a similar error if use an array with multiple elements in place of the filename:

```
$ set aa bb
$ echo foo > "$@"
bash: "$@": ambiguous redirect
```

As mentioned in answers to [stderr redirection not working in csh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35715/170373), the `>&` operator works in (t)csh to redirect both stdout and stderr.  `2>&1` is the standard way to redirect stderr to the same place as stdout, but (t)csh doesn't support that. Instead, it takes the combination `> foo 2>&1`  as a redirection to `foo`, a regular argument `2`, and a redirection to `1`, and the redirections conflict, so you get the error.

`>&` also works in Bash and zsh, but isn't a standard feature.

Answer (score -1):

The second entry should work fine. The "ambiguous redirect" error sometimes happens if you either have spaces where they shouldn't be, or conversely when an important space is missing.

I would simplify your command to demonstrate:

```
echo "Test" >/tmp/x.txt 2>&1 &
```

The ">/tmp/x.txt" part will redirect stdout (file handle #1). A space between the > and the file name is permitted (although in this context would be confusing), but otherwise there should not be any spaces in here.

The 2>&1 will redirect stderr (file handle 2) to whatever file handle 1 goes to (which is stdout). There must not be any spaces in here, either.

The & will background your task. This must be offset with a space from the preceding character.

Reversing the two redirections does not work (although echo is a poor choice here since it does not produce stderr output):

```
echo "This will not work" 2>&1 >/tmp/x.txt &
```

This means:

```
2>&1
```

Redirect file handle 2 to where file handle 1 goes (which at this point is still the console)

```
>/tmp/x.txt
```

Redirect file handle 1 to a file - but since file handle 2 (stderr) is *already* redirected at this point, it will keep its destination and still go to the console.

The first command you wrote is simply a syntax error.

```
echo &>/tmp/x.txt
```

*Update*: @Wildcard pointed out in the comments that this is actually valid syntax.

Comment: `The ">/tmp/x.txt" part will redirect stdout (file handle #1). It must not contain any spaces.` .
 It can contain the space. `command >out.txt ` == `command > out.txt`

Comment: You are right; I made a mistake there. Fixing it.

Comment: "The first command you wrote is simply a syntax error."  No, it's not; it's the *preferred* Bash syntax for redirecting both stdout and stderr.  See `LESS='+/Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error' man bash`

Comment: @Wildcard - thanks. I never stop learning!